# Navigation bar won't toggle

Tags: html, button, navigationbar, togglebutton

The button to toggle the nav bar won't function.  I've checked through the answers to similar questions and can't see anything wrong with my html. Help much appreciated!

I can see all the li items in my navbar but cannot hide them.

Here's the relevant html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" id="home">Simmo Simpson</a>
        </div>

        <div class="pull-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="#myNavbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
            <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#contact" >Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I've also included this at the bottom (and stylesheets etc in the meta section):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: try adding `script` tag in head section

Comment: Thanks @Mandar. I'd already done that but not working

Comment: have u added BT's css file

Comment: Thanks @Mandar... I'm not sure what that means. What is BT? Button? If so, I'm not sure what button CSS file is :/

Comment: BT is Shorthand of bootstrap

Comment: I want to say that have u added following link <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

Answer (score 0):

First off, add `type="text/javascript"` to the script tags for jquery/javascript includes.

Thirdly, check your server/site/browser configuration in terms of 'cross-site scripting'. I believe this may be your issue here. When you call a script with cross-origin, you are trying to execute the script remotely and for security purposes this tends to be disabled by default for a lot of web sites and/or servers. To get around this, I would recommend downloading the bootstrap CSS/JS files and referencing them from your sites director as apposed to a CDN.

---

I also see that you had an issue where by you included a '#' in an element id;
`<div id="#myNavbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse" >` - Upon fixing this the code stopped working, this is because you may not have changed the target ID of the bootstrap toggle button, see; `<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">`.

In both of these lines the ID's need to match, that being the ID of the navbar element to be toggled, and the button that does the toggling.

Comment: Thanks @JokerDan  I've added 'type="text/javascript' to the script tags at the bottom of the body section but it's still not working.   Before I posted my question, the button had been working using the CDN but then something happened and it stopped. For that reason, I imagine downloading the bootstrap CSs/JS files won't solve it, but I'm trying anyway.  How do I link those files to my html? Is it with the following script? '<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>'  Thanks!

Comment: I needed to delete the hashtag from the id in the div element. See my full answer, above.

Comment: Now it's stopped working again even though I haven't changed anything. Any idea why that might happen?

Comment: @sim If you have deleted the '#' out of `<div id="#myNavbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse" >` - You also need to delete the '#' out of the target for the toggle button, see; `<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">` - Change this to the following; `<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="myNavbar">`. Hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks @JokerDan Unfortunately that's made no difference.